# How could I find those git documents('Everyday Git[1]' & 'Git User's Manual[2]') mentioned in the man pages?

Tags: git

The [git(1)](http://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/git.1.html) manual page says:

```
See gittutorial(7) to get started, then see Everyday Git[1]
for a useful minimum set of commands. The Git User’s Manual[2] 
has a more in-depth introduction.
```

Where is either "Everyday Git[1]" or "Git User's Manual[2]"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The links can be found at the very end of the man page:

```
    1. Git User’s Manual
       file:///usr/local/share/doc/git/user-manual.html

    2. Git concepts chapter of the user-manual
       file:///usr/local/share/doc/git/user-manual.html#git-concepts

    3. howto
       file:///usr/local/share/doc/git/howto-index.html

    4. Git API documentation
       file:///usr/local/share/doc/git/technical/api-index.html

    5. git@vger.kernel.org
       mailto:git@vger.kernel.org
```

The `[number]` notation usually means that it references some document, and at the end of (page,document,...) you can find location of these documents. I encourage you to look around more before asking the question ;)

Comment: Thank you so much for both your answer and patient advice! I didn't understand this notation and just can't express my foolish!

Comment: @IsaacShee You're welcome.